# How to place data labels on stacked bar chart with categorical variables in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I place data labels on stacked bar charts using the following data set and code. I am getting  `Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: y and label` when I used `+ geom_text(aes(X = Educational_status))`.

```
Age Sex Educational_status  State
44  Male    Illiterate       A
35  Male    PG               B
60  Male    UG               C
45  Female  Illiterate       D
45  Female  UG               A
34  Female  Illiterate       A

ggplot(data2, aes(x= Educational_status, fill=Sex))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack")+ 
   + facet_grid( ~ State)
```

Comment: What labels do you want to put on your bar chart? The issue is probably that geom_bar by default computes its `y` value under the hood, while geom_text does not.

Comment: I want to have bars for the Education_Status stacked in different color for Sex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. To add labels on a bar chart there are at least two approaches. Either approach requires to compute the `y` values to place the labels and to map something on the `label` aes.

1. Using `geom_bar` you have to tell ggplot2 to compute the `count` on the fly inside `geom_text` by setting `stat = "count"`. If you want to use the `count` for the labels as well, you could make use of `after_stat(count)`.
2. The probably easier way would be to aggregate the data using e.g. `dplyr::count` before passing it to ggplot and making use of `geom_col`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data2, aes(x = Educational_status, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count)), stat = "count", position = "stack", vjust = 0) +
  facet_grid(. ~ State)
```

[image]

```r
library(dplyr)

data3 <- data2 %>%
  count(Educational_status, Sex, State, name = "count")

ggplot(data3, aes(x = Educational_status, y = count, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = count), position = "stack", vjust = 0) +
  facet_grid(. ~ State)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
data2 <- structure(list(Age = c(44L, 35L, 60L, 45L, 45L, 34L), Sex = c(
  "Male",
  "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female"
), Educational_status = c(
  "Illiterate",
  "PG", "UG", "Illiterate", "UG", "Illiterate"
), State = c(
  "A",
  "B", "C", "D", "A", "A"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -6L
))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say if there will be multiple people with the same credentials, but if there is only one, then this gives you the labels:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x = Educational_status, y = 1, fill = Sex, label = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid( ~ State)
```

Change the `vjust` to move the label up or down, and `label = Sex` if you want a different label

[image]